# If it is possible, how do I create a custom field containing a document number on NetSuite in a saved search?

Tags: formula, netsuite, calculated-columns, saved-searches

In NetSuite, I am setting up a new (currently untitled) saved search that is meant to display three columns simultaneously: Invoice document number, Sales Order document number and Item Fulfillment document number.

I have configured my transaction saved search to display invoice document type. Sales Order document number is called `Created From` which is a NetSuite-created field and displays normally as desired.

There is a field called `Document Number`, unfortunately it responds closely to the criteria setting whether document types are set to Invoice or set to Item Fulfillment. Setting both does not meet my desired output.

I believe there is a way to somehow have all three document numbers present in the same saved search as their own unique columns.

While editing the saved search, I have attempted to create a new column called "Formula (text)" which is a field containing the formula `{number}`, this column appears as a second Invoice document number instead of the desired Item Fulfillment document number.

While editing the saved search, I have also tried another "Formula (text)" field containing the formula `{tranid}` which also results as another Invoice document number column instead of the desired Item Fulfillment document number.

Result of both above attempts: https://i.ibb.co/KyDP7Z5/2019-06-12-13-55-58-Window.png

I tried going to `Customization > Lists, Records & Fields > Transaction Line Fields` to create a new custom field, containing the above as defaulted formulas. The result is exactly that of the above image.

I tried going to `Customization > Lists, Records & Fields > Transaction Body Fields` to create a new custom field, where the content is referenced by another Saved Search. I expected that if I can pick the document number column from the "item fulfillment lookup" saved search, then that would appear as a separate column bearing the Item Fulfillment number.

I marked the document number column inside the "item fulfillment lookup" saved search as the summary type: "group" as well as give this saved search "Document Number" as an available filter in order for the "item fulfillment lookup" saved search to appear for custom columns.

Unfortunately, this yielded an empty blank column.

I know and I admit that I am doing something incorrect and would much appreciate it if there is an alternative solution or workaround to achieve this desired objective (all three document numbers to appear in a single saved search).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your saved search Columns, at the end of the drop down list where you choose the columns, you can choose related records fields.

You didn't say which record your search is based on, but assuming your search criteria is on Sales Order, then you can use the following:

To get the related Item Fulfillment:

**Fulfilling/Receiving Transaction Fields ...**  and then choose Document Number

To get the related Invoice:

**Applying Transaction fields ...** and then choose Document Number

Comment: Following your advice, I've set the Criteria from `Type: Invoice` into `Type: Sales Order` https://i.ibb.co/zN2xDDR/1.png then I've added in your suggested fields to the Results tab https://i.ibb.co/9G9F6QH/2.png . Here are my results https://i.ibb.co/Fg9QMb9/3.png . Do you know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Solved it. I turned off Main Line and refined my criteria so that the appropriate entries are being shown. Thank you for your answer. This is marked as the solution now.